# Git sparse checkout^ some root folders fully recursive, some other root folders without subfolders

Tags: git, sparse-checkout, git-sparse-checkout

I use git **2.40** and I have repo folder structure like this:

```
└── root_dir1
│   ├── dir11              
│   │   └── file11
│   │
│   └── dir12
│   │   └── file12
│   │   
│   └── file13
│
└── root_dir2
    ├── dir21         
    │   └── sub_dir21a
    │   │   │
    │   │   └── file21
    │   │   
    │   └── file22
    │
    └── file23
```

I need to checkout:

1. Files that are placed directly in **root_dir1** (exclude all subfolders with all it's content) - **file13** in my specific example.
2. Files that are placed directly in **root_dir2** and directly in **dir21** subfolder (exclude all other subfolders with all it's content) - **file22** and **file23** in my specific example.

I've tried the following:

```
git clone --no-checkout --sparse repo_URL
git sparse-checkout set root_dir1 root_dir2
git checkout
```

After that I've edited `.git\info\sparse-checkout` and added some negative patterns:

```
/*
!/*/
/root_dir1/
/root_dir2/
#added some negative patterns
!/root_dir1/*/
!/root_dir2/dir21/*/
```

And finally I called `git sparse-checkout reapply`. But I've received a warning:

```
warning: unrecognized negative pattern: '/root_dir2/dir21/*' warning:
disabling cone pattern matching
```

Despite of this warning I got exactly the files that I needed - looks like it's working. But I'm curious what's wrong with my negative patterns? Why `!/root_dir1/*/` is valid but `!/root_dir2/dir21/*/` not? And why it is working correctly despite of that?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the [expected patterns in cone mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout#_internalscone_pattern_set) are in the form
(white lines added for clarity):

```
/*
!/*/

/dirA/
!/dirA/*/

/dirA/dirB/
!/dirA/dirB/*/

/dirA/dirB/dirC/
```

(this would be the result of running `git sparse-checkout add dirA/dirB/dirC`)

i.e. some directories where everything below is present (in this example `dirC`)
and all their parent directories are present with their files but not their directories (in this example the root directory, `dirA` and `dirB`)

which is not what you have. To not get the warnings you would need:

```
/*
!/*/
/root_dir1/
!/root_dir1/*/
/root_dir2/
!/root_dir2/*/
/root_dir2/dir21/
!/root_dir2/dir21/*/
```

which makes `git sparse-checkout reapply` works without warning and leave you in cone mode:

```
cat .git/config.worktree
[core]
        sparseCheckout = true
        sparseCheckoutCone = true
```

(tested with Git 2.42.0)